# Why is my font size of 1.1em way too large?

Tags: css, font-size

When I change my `font-size` from 1em to 1.1em, the font changes to a huge size. It looks like about size 48px or something. It should only increase by 10%.

```
* {
  font-size: 1.1em;
}
```

Comment: Using `*` selectors in CSS is always dangerous.

Comment: ray hatfield’s explanation is correct; I recommend the fix of setting it on `body` instead of on every element.

Comment: Why on the body? Why is * dangerous?

Answer (score 4):

Because with that selector every nested element increases the size by 10%. You might want `1.1rem` instead, or better yet, just set [`:root { font-size: 18px; }`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:root)

Answer (score 1):

@ray hatfield's answer is correct.

As an alternative, you might want to change the `*` selector of this rule to `html`.

```
html {
  font-size: 1.1em;
}
```

This way only the "basic font-size" (defined for the `html` tag, which is defined by the browser's default settings) will be increased by 10%, and all other font sizes (but *only* those with a *relative*  unit like `em` or `rem` will change accordingly.